# this.Resources throws a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to access an app resource from my resources like this:

```
LinearGradientBrush lb = Application.Current.Resources["FFG"] as LinearGradientBrush;
```

However, this throws a NullReferenceException. I tried this code to see what was null:

```
Debug.WriteLine(this.Resources.Count());
```

Also returned a NullReferenceException.

What's even stranger is that this works:

```
(Storyboard)this.Resources["LayersOut"]).Begin();
```

Can this.Resources possibly be null, even when I have all of this in the resources area of the XAML?

Note that my code above is ran after InitializeComponent();

(Removed all of the storyboards for ease of reading)

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PrecipBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF490000" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFE8E8E8" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF2044E4" Offset="0.838"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF17A598" Offset="0.653"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF22BB00" Offset="0.445"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFE800" Offset="0.253"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFF0202" Offset="0.125"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MRMS" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFAB59FD" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF2044E4" Offset="0.838"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF17A598" Offset="0.653"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF22BB00" Offset="0.445"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF005D00" Offset="0.253"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.125"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="FFG" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF460055" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF23FF00" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.815"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Magenta" Offset="0.253"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFB400A3" Offset="0.125"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFB69D00" Offset="0.642"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFB60000" Offset="0.43"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DroughtKey" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF490000" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD100" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFB67C00" Offset="0.653"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF746400" Offset="0.445"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.253"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ForestFire" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF490000" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD100" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.253"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="QPF" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF68FF00" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF28B000" Offset="0.838"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF0800BB" Offset="0.445"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF00FFD1" Offset="0.253"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFDC00FF" Offset="0.125"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF126300" Offset="0.626"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Temp" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF070097" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF035FFF" Offset="0.838"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF23FF00" Offset="0.445"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.253"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFF5D00" Offset="0.125"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF00FFF3" Offset="0.626"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PrecipAvg" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF661C00" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF17A600" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF26EC4A" Offset="0.838"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCFF00" Offset="0.445"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFF8000" Offset="0.253"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF9B3800" Offset="0.125"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF65E040" Offset="0.626"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PrecipHour" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF661C00" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF0011BF" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF265CEC" Offset="0.838"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF2EFF00" Offset="0.445"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF3FF00" Offset="0.253"/>
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.125"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF65E040" Offset="0.626"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: Could you share your code (in the xaml.cs file) as well?

Comment: The full resources code?  pastebin.com/UW0iK16Z

Comment: Not the resources code. I'd like to see the C# code that uses those resources. It is in the page's code-behind file, right?

Comment: Yes. This is the line that throws the exeption: LinearGradientBrush lb = Application.Current.Resources["FFG"] as LinearGradientBrush;

Answer (score 0):

Application.Current.Resources refers to the resources defined in App.xaml, not the current page. Try accessing this way in the code behind:

```
    LinearGradientBrush lb = this.Resources["FFG"] as LinearGradientBrush;
```

or move the brush definition on App.xaml and then your code should work too:

```
   LinearGradientBrush lb = Application.Current.Resources["FFG"] as LinearGradientBrush;
```

Comment: Still throws NullReferenceExeption.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the code where you try to access the resource? I tried both of the above solutions and they work for the XAML code you gave.

Comment: here's the full code for the resources: http://pastebin.com/UW0iK16Z. The actual c# code is ran after the user opens the app, clicks a button which opens a list, and clicks a specific item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the following code in your `App.xaml`:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Path to your resource file" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you'll can get it like this:

```
LinearGradientBrush lb = Application.Current.Resources["FFG"] as LinearGradientBrush;
```

Comment: There is no resources file, it is all located inside the MainPage.xaml. Is that what I should reference?

Comment: @Kevin you need to create `ResourceDictionary` file in your project and write path to it.

Comment: Implemented and it still throws a NullReferenceExeption.                                                Project Abandonment Meter: 0%[##########__]100%

Comment: Do you put your brushes into this dictionary? I just tried it in my project and it works fine.

Comment: I put this in the App.xaml, because there doesn't seem to be any reason to create a seperate file when it can be referenced inside the ResourceDictionary itself http://pastebin.com/8Cat5UE1

Comment: @Kevin Show me how you calling now your resource in code?

Comment: LinearGradientBrush lb = Application.Current.Resources["FFG"] as LinearGradientBrush;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70859/discussion-between-kevin-and-rendishen).